# figcaption displaying over img, but figcaption border displaying behind img on hover

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have 3 images with figcaptions with borders in the center of them. The images are set to .5 opacity and then 1.0 opacity on hover. I want the figcaptions and their borders to stay on top of the images always. Right now, the figcaptions and their borders are underneath the images, and when I hover the figcaption text moves in front of the image and the figcaption borders move to the back.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <section class="icons">
               <div id="logo-container">
               <figure>
        <img src="/Users/laurenkunz/Desktop/Design Projects/laurenkunz.com/logoicon-01.png" alt="Logo design photo" height="32">
        <figcaption class="logodesigncaption">Logo Design</figcaption>
  </figure></div>
    <div id="invitation-container"><figure>
      <img src="laurenkunz.com/invitationicon-01-01.png" alt="Invitation design photo" width="541">
      <figcaption class="invitationscaption">Invitations</figcaption>
    </figure></div>
      <div id="website-container"><figure>
        <img src="laurenkunz.com/websitesicon-01.png" alt="Website design photo" width="639">
        <figcaption class="websitedesignicon">Website Design</figcaption>
      </figure></div>
      </section>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#logo-container img{
    width:400px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);/*For IE and earlier*/
}

#invitation-container img{
    width: 400px;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);/*For IE and earlier*/
}

#website-container img{
    width: 400px;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);/*For IE and earlier*/
}
.icons  img{
    height: 400px;;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
#logo-container img:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);/*For IE and earlier*/
}
#invitation-container img:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);/*For IE and earlier*/
}
#website-container img:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);/*For IE and earlier*/
}


#logo-container{

    border-style: solid;
}
#invitation-container{

    border-style: solid;

}
#website-container{

    border-style:solid;
}

.icons, #website-container, #logo-container, #invitation-container{

min-width: 500px;
margin: 10px;
display:inline-block;
}

figcaption{
border-style: solid;
font-size: 36px;
display: table-caption;
width: 250px;
padding: 10px 20px 20px;
margin: -220px 100px 100px 75px;
text-align: center;

}
```

I know it's kind of a mess, sorry! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a relatively unknown (and often frustrating) quirk of the `opacity` property in CSS. [Opacity values than than 1 change the stacking context of the item they're on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

If I understand your initial statement correctly, something like the CSS below should fix you up:

```
figcaption {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

If you're still running into issues, putting up an example CodePen or JSFiddle will help us determine exactly the issue exactly and put forth more accurate CSS.  Hope that helps!